# find some text in content in div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery find and replace string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115152/jquery-find-and-replace-string)

This is my html:

```
<div class="dt_lft">There is an error</div>
```

I need to find whether the div has the text `error` and replace that text with `success` using class name. How to do this?

Comment: First have to try yourself after post here,  this is the rule

Comment: "There is an success"? :)

Comment: Here's a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115152/jquery-find-and-replace-string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("div.dt_lft:contains('error')").text(function(i,text){
   return text.replace('error', 'success');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ztCcB/1/

---

`$("div.dt_lft:contains('error')")` returns all divs with class `dt_lft` containing word `error`, you can read more about jQuery [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). With jQuery [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) you can write function like:

```
$(object).text(function(index,CurrentContent){
   //somecode here
}
```

---

Elsewhere, if your object contains word `error` many times, you can do:

```
text.split('error').join('success');
```

In case you do not want to use RegEx.

Comment: I love the fact that this gets accepted, despite being pretty much identical to mine... Oh, I love SO!

Comment: @BenM it's me, upvoter of your comment :D

Comment: @loler - there is no justice in this world... :-P

Comment: Just for reference, using `.split('string').join('string')` is a **lot** slower than using RegExp!

Comment: @BenM you know, i just try to avoid regular expressions, coz people asking such question usually are not fluent in it. But of course it must be mentioned.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
$("div.dt_lft:contains('error')").text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace('error', 'success');
});
```

If it's likely that the string `error` will occur more than once in the text, you'll need to use a RegEx to handle that:

```
$("div.dt_lft:contains('error')").text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace(new RegExp('error', 'g'), 'success');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var m=$(".dt_lft").html();
m=m.replace("error","success");
$(".dt_lft").html(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if($("div.dt_lft:contains('error')")){
  $('.dt_lft').replace('error','success');
}
```