# HTML/Javascript : Text field with different font colors, sizes, fonts, integrated

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to write a page in HTML using CSS and Javascript.  One of the main features is to generate a large text file in a single location (the home page) that is able to color-code certain words and terms to help the eye jump to important phrases.  This needs to be done at runtime, with the user being able to continually add on to the log.

Can anyone recommend a library that implements such a thing?  I've looked into CKEditor, but from what I gather it only useful when writing static web pages.

If I use an iFrame, can I accomplish the same thing but using Javascript to alter its html, and then embed it on my main page again and be able to edit it in real time?  (Real time as in whenever the user hits a "submit" form.)  For example, telling Javascript to add on a string with the appropriate html tags so that a word in the middle of the sentence can use CSS tags to change it color or font, then close the tag to have it return to the default?

Thanks!  My new Jr. Programmer job starts soon and I'm basically plunging myself into the web languages that I know little about.

Comment: "generate a large text file in a single location (the home page)", well this line is confusing. Try to put your question in simple words for good number of responses, also try to put some visuals(drawing, snapshots) of what you want, it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  What I am trying to do is have a text box that supports different text colors that the user can scroll up and down, select continuously and copy-paste elsewhere without having to manually select each different color segment of text.

Comment: To further describe what I want, imagine you are playing a game with a GUI, just a few buttons like "Go Left" and "Go Right." The story is conveyed using a text box that continually has new information being added to it.  So, the log has "You go left and see a car.  You go right and see a bus."  The words 'car' and 'bus' have a blue font to separate them from the rest of the text.  However, the log should be kept in a scrollable box so the page isn't continually being stretched higher.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is useful. Also look at the second answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115152/jquery-find-and-replace-string) question for how to search and replace a string. You'd of course want to replace it with a string wrapped in a span with another class specified.

If you are getting into JavaScript, "JavaScript: The Good Parts" by Douglas Crockford is worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

use `<span></span>` to wrap your word through `javascript`, then check that word for (your apps)keyword then change color of that span using `css`. it will give you color-code for your log

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out that I should be using a ScrollBox for what I want to do.  I had previously thought I couldn't do this because when using a form, it would just straight print out the CSS tags as text.

Thanks for your guys' suggestions!