# change table cell value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to find a table cell that contains certain text value and change that to something else.

```
    <table><tr>
<td>You are nice</td>
<td>I hate you</td>
</tr></table>
```

Find the table cell that contains "I hate you" and change that to "I love you".

How do I do that in Jquery?

Comment: You could look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115152/jquery-find-and-replace-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `:contains` selector:

```
$('td:contains("I hate you")').text('....');
```

Using `filter` method:

```
$('td').filter(function(){
   // contains
   return $(this).text().indexOf("I hate you") > -1;
   // exact match
   // return $(this).text() === "I hate you";
}).text('...');
```

Or:

```
$('td').text(function(i, text){
   return text.replace('I hate you', 'I love you!');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple `contains` selector should do the trick followed by setting the text value

```
$("td:contains('I hate you')").text('I love you');
```

[contains selector ref](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: Works good but note this would also select td's containing the text "I hate you all" etcetera... (not exact match)

Comment: @jtheman lol you did use the term *contains* in your question :) but out of interest what's the thinking behind this? There's a code smell here when your looking to swap a text value rather than explicit matching on table cells by id for example...

Answer (score 0):

Use querySelectorAll("td"), iterate over all returned elements and check the textNode's value.

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll("td");
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    if (tds[i].firstChild.nodeValue == "I hate you"){
        tds[i].firstChild.nodeValue = "I love you";
    }
}
```