# Change table value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the value of an `td` value with the button that is clicked.. I have tried a couple of ways but none have worked. If user click Show `USD` button column show only `USD` values, If user click `GBP` column should show `GBP` values. I don't know this this is correct way to do this. Any help highly appreciated.

```js
$('.btn-usd').on('click', function(){
    $("cu-usd").removeClass(hide);
    $("cu-gbp").addClass(hide);
});
$('.btn-gbp').on('click', function(){
    $("cu-gbp").removeClass(hide);
    $("cu-usd").addClass(hide);
});
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-usd">show USD</div>
<div class="btn-gbp">show GBP</div>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr> 
            <td>
                <div class="cu-usd">$10</div>
                <div class="cu-gbp">£7.10</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="cu-usd">$20</div>
                <div class="cu-gbp">£14.20</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="cu-usd">$30</div>
                <div class="cu-gbp">£21.30</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="cu-usd">$40</div>
                <div class="cu-gbp">£28.10</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr> 
            <td>
                <div class="cu-usd">$100</div>
                <div class="cu-gbp">£70.10</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="cu-usd">$200</div>
                <div class="cu-gbp">£140.20</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="cu-usd">$300</div>
                <div class="cu-gbp">£210.30</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="cu-usd">$400</div>
                <div class="cu-gbp">£280.10</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: SEE THIS:     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763148/change-table-cell-value-jquery

Comment: it has some syntax errors,otherwise its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(".cu-usd").removeClass('hide');
$(".cu-gbp").addClass('hide');
$('.btn-usd').on('click', function(){
     $(".cu-usd").removeClass('hide');
     $(".cu-gbp").addClass('hide');
    });
    $('.btn-gbp').on('click', function(){
     $(".cu-gbp").removeClass('hide');
     $(".cu-usd").addClass('hide');
    });
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-usd">show USD</div>
    <div class="btn-gbp">show GBP</div>
    
    
    <table>
     <tbody>
      <tr> 
       <td><div class="cu-usd">$10</div><div class="cu-gbp">£7.10</div></td>
       <td><div class="cu-usd">$20</div><div class="cu-gbp">£14.20</div></td>
       <td><div class="cu-usd">$30</div><div class="cu-gbp">£21.30</div></td>
       <td><div class="cu-usd">$40</div><div class="cu-gbp">£28.10</div></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
     <tbody>
      <tr> 
       <td><div class="cu-usd">$100</div><div class="cu-gbp">£70.10</div></td>
       <td><div class="cu-usd">$200</div><div class="cu-gbp">£140.20</div></td>
       <td><div class="cu-usd">$300</div><div class="cu-gbp">£210.30</div></td>
       <td><div class="cu-usd">$400</div><div class="cu-gbp">£280.10</div></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: You forgot _quotes_ around `hide`

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 problems

1. Class selector starts with `.`
2. hide is a string must be in quotes

Following will work

```
 $('.btn-usd').on('click', function(){
        $(".cu-usd").removeClass("hide");
        $(".cu-gbp").addClass("hide");
    });
    $('.btn-gbp').on('click', function(){
        $(".cu-gbp").removeClass("hide");
        $(".cu-usd").addClass("hide");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.btn-usd').on('click', function() {

  $(".cu-usd").removeClass('hide');//missing .
  $(".cu-gbp").addClass('hide');//missing .
});
$('.btn-gbp').on('click', function() {
  $(".cu-gbp").removeClass('hide');//missing .
  $(".cu-usd").addClass('hide');//missing .
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-usd">show USD</div>
<div class="btn-gbp">show GBP</div>


<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="cu-usd">$10</div>
        <div class="cu-gbp">£7.10</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cu-usd">$20</div>
        <div class="cu-gbp">£14.20</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cu-usd">$30</div>
        <div class="cu-gbp">£21.30</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cu-usd">$40</div>
        <div class="cu-gbp">£28.10</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="cu-usd">$100</div>
        <div class="cu-gbp">£70.10</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cu-usd">$200</div>
        <div class="cu-gbp">£140.20</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cu-usd">$300</div>
        <div class="cu-gbp">£210.30</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="cu-usd">$400</div>
        <div class="cu-gbp">£280.10</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Missing `.` in class name

Comment: You can also use the `.hide() and .show()` @techies [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37966176/change-table-value-using-jquery/37966406#37966406)

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code.

```
$('.btn-usd').on('click', function(){
  $(".cu-usd").removeClass('hide');
  $(".cu-gbp").addClass('hide');
});
$('.btn-gbp').on('click', function(){
 $(".cu-gbp").removeClass('hide');
 $(".cu-usd").addClass('hide');
});
```

Use `.` operator for class element and wrap hide in quotes as it is passed as string.

Also to optimize take out `$(".cu-usd")` and `$(".cu-gbp")` in variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with `.hide()` and `.show()` and don't *have* to assign a class. The result is the same.

and as mentioned before missing `.` in classname. But I think that you know that by now.

```js
 $('.btn-usd').on('click', function(){
        $(".cu-usd").show();
        $(".cu-gbp").hide();
       });
    $('.btn-gbp').on('click', function(){
        $(".cu-gbp").show();
        $(".cu-usd").hide();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-usd">show USD</div>
<div class="btn-gbp">show GBP</div>
    <table>
     <tbody>
      <tr> 
       <td><div class="cu-usd">$10</div><div class="cu-gbp">£7.10</div></td>
       <td><div class="cu-usd">$20</div><div class="cu-gbp">£14.20</div></td>
       <td><div class="cu-usd">$30</div><div class="cu-gbp">£21.30</div></td>
       <td><div class="cu-usd">$40</div><div class="cu-gbp">£28.10</div></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
     <tbody>
      <tr> 
       <td><div class="cu-usd">$100</div><div class="cu-gbp">£70.10</div></td>
       <td><div class="cu-usd">$200</div><div class="cu-gbp">£140.20</div></td>
       <td><div class="cu-usd">$300</div><div class="cu-gbp">£210.30</div></td>
       <td><div class="cu-usd">$400</div><div class="cu-gbp">£280.10</div></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
```