# Replacing characters in specific class declaration

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to use isotope in connection with a CuteNews system, and to get the filtering to work I need to print some identifiers in my class declaration of each isotope-item.
[Link to Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html)

In CuteNews my news items can have multiple categories assigned to them, so when I load them up in my HTML they could belong to e.g. "Domestic" and "Food" at the same time, which could be e.g. category no. 1 and 5. In CuteNews the only way I can get the category extracted and tossed into my HTML is to use a function that prints all categories as a string, that reads "1,2,5,21" if the categories are 1, 2, 5 and 21. Now that is no good if I need to add it as a class in isotope, as this would produce

```
<div class="isotope-item 1,2,5,21">...content...</div>
```

So I need some way of transforming the above (which is what ends up in my HTML right now) into

```
<div class="isotope-item cat1 cat2 cat5 cat21">...content...</div>
```

This way I could apply the isotope filtering on e.g. all classes with cat1 and so on.

As I see it I need to strip away the commas, which could be done easily using some JS like this [jQuery find and replace string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115152/jquery-find-and-replace-string). But I don't want to replace all commas on my entire page!

How can I target only what is inside the class="isotope-item" DIV and put a "cat" in front of each number and then replace the comma with a space?

Comment: .attr('class').replace('isotope-item ', 'isotope-item ,').replaceAll(',', ' cat');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a replace like

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('isotope-item'),
    el, array;
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    el = els[i];
    el.className = el.className.replace(/(\d+)(,|$|\s)/g, function (all, value) {
        return 'cat' + value + ' '
    })
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/snxeqnpc/)

Comment: That looks awesome. I will give it a go when I return home this evening!

Comment: OK, so your code actually works pretty good, but I forgot that I was using Bootstrap, so my DIV actually have 3 other classes assigned, that have numbers in them... The whole DIV code is: <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 isotope-item 1,2,3,4,5,6>...content...</div>. I could of course just make a dublicate of the col-classes and call them something that doesn't have numbers in them, but is there a way to make it work, so the code doesn't replace the numbers in the bootstrap classes?

Comment: OK, I think the easiest thing is to make some copy of the bootstrap classes for the pages using the isotope script. I am going to mark your reply as the answer. Thanks a million!

Comment: Extremely nice. Thank you!