# jQuery / SharePoint 2013 text replacing issue

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013

I have faced a problem with replacing one text to another on my SharePoint 2013 survey:

[image: survey checkbox]

I would like to replace this text: `"Specify your own value:"` with `"marshmellows"`.

Unfortunately this code doesn't work. I am a noob with SP and jquery.
I was basing on this article:
[jQuery find and replace string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115152/jquery-find-and-replace-string)

Here is my code:

```js
$(document.body).find('*').each(function() {
    var tmp = $(this).children().remove();
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.replace("Specify your own value:", "marshmellows");
    $(this).text(text);
    $(this).append(tmp);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div>
    <p>
      <h1>
        <a>Specify your own value:</a>
      </h1>
    </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $(document.body) seems wrong. Try just using $(body) or $(document body). Failing that, you can try using $("#s4-workspace"), which is the id of the body container used in Sharepoint.